# content type view into hidden region

Tags: theming

I would like to create and display content type in a hidden region. The only reason to hide the region is to prevent moving the location. It is for flash file header banner that will be changed by a user by adding or modifying the content type. If it must be a block, then I suppose it doesn't much matter if the region is visible or not. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you could also try the [Boxes module](http://drupal.org/project/boxes) or even [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and [Panels Everywhere](http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere).

Comment: @Laxman13 - Thanks, will look at the box, but it relies on regions, much like a block, so I need to see what they mean by: "place it in a region and click 'configure' next to the box name to restrict where it shows up"

Panels, is something I thought about, though in my dev team here there is reluctance to go that route for anything with folk comparing it to the old "frames" concept. Go figure!

As things get closer, I will see how to populate a hidden region, but thus far, it seems to be module driven and not content type/views driven.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable in code, you may find it easier to add the flash banner in [hook_preprocess_page](http://drupal.org/node/223430), that way it isn't exposed to blocks admin.

e.g, template.php

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  $flash_embed_code = ''; // TODO, get flash embed code.
  $vars['flash_banner'] = $flash_embed_code;
}
```

Then, in page.tpl.php

```
if (!empty($flash_banner)) { print $flash_banner; }
```